# Classifying the critical points of a three variables function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let
$$
f(x,y, z)=x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2z^2
$$
be a three variables function. Find and classify its critical points.

**Solution.**
I found and classified the eight critical points $(+-1, +-1, +-1)$ (given the simmetries of the function, should they all be of the same type?), using the eigenvalues criterium, though I am stuck with classifying the critical point $(0,0,0)$, since the Hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated in $(0,0,0)$ is the zero matrix. How could I proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$f(t) \equiv f(at,bt,ct) = (a^4+b^4+c^4)t^4-2a^2b^2c^2t^6$$

which gives the "shape" of the function in any direction. The derivative is given by

$$f'(t) = 4t^3(a^4+b^4+c^4-3a^2b^2c^2t^2)$$

For $|t| < \frac{\sqrt{a^4+b^4+c^4}}{\sqrt{3}|abc|}$ for $a,b,c \neq 0$, we have that the derivative is negative to the left, but positive to the right. The same thing happens when we let some of $a,b,c$ be $0$ (they cannot all be zero at once because that is not a valid direction).

Thus the function is concave up in all directions, and $(0,0,0)$ is a local min.